# Android Action Bar search in Grid View.

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

i want to implement **Native search in action bar** , where it **filter a data of grid view**.Grid view contains images and text which was set using custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Use this for setting up searchview in actionbar and

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/app/LauncherActivity.java.shtml

for implementing filerable in a listview.

Comment: just change listview to gridview.